# How to let library users rewrite some parts of the library?

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to write a library for a text based game called `avalon`. The game uses different dialogues at various points of time to help the players. Currently I have a file called `dialogues.py` in this format

```py
# avalon/dialogues.py
start_game = "welcome to the game"
next_round = "write `next` if you are ready"

def choices(options):
    sent = "Choose one of the following options:\n"
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        sent += f"{i}) {option}\n"
    return sent
```

These dialogues are then imported in various files in different parts of the game

```py
# avalon/a.py
from avalon.dialogues import start_game, choices

print(start_game)
print(choices(["op-1", "op-2"]))
```

```py
# avalon/b.py
from avalon.dialogues import next_round, choices

print(next_round)
print(choices(["op-1", "op-2", "op-3"]))
```

Now I want the users of the library to be able to rewrite these dialogues. What is the most pythonic way to do this?

I am thinking about using something like the following in both `a.py` and `b.py` to get this done. This requires the users to copy `dialogues.py` in the root folder, and then edit the file.

```py
try:
    import dialogues as dlg
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from avalon import dialogues as dlg

print(dlg.start_game)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you mean like a `class`?

Comment: @yakir0 I don't get what you are asking about. Are you suggesting to put all these dialogues in a class and let the user inherit that? But then again, those dialogues are used at various places. I don't understand how the client should use the inherited class. There is not one single class where this could be given.

Comment: No, like creating a class `Dialogue` which contains the `start_game` and `next_round` attributes... Each 'user' will have it's own instance and will be able to change them without effecting other instances

Comment: @yakir0 Yes that is what I was thinking about. You are suggesting to put all those dialogues inside `Dialogue` class, then I create instance of `dlg = Dialogue()` in each file. So then users will be able to rewrite the dialogues with `Dialogue.start_game = "Helloo"`. But then I need to somehow make sure that these overwriting are evaluated before creating those instances.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a mistake or not but it should be `dlg.start_game = "Helloo"` not `Dialogue.start_game = "Helloo"`.
Anyway if you want a custom setter you can use `@property`.
I think your question should be more focused.